# Intervention response() throwing error

Tags: php, intervention

I am using Intervention library to process image. I have included a script `viewImage.php` which takes the name of the image and the image size from the URL like this

> http://localhost/oop/viewImage.php?image_name=14526&image_size=thumb

Then using the filename and file size I am doing this

```
$img = Image::make($file_path.$image_name);
```

and then show the image like this `echo $img->response();`

I also have an autoloader which loads the required classes of my project.
This is my autoloader

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

But every time I hit the URL I get this error

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'classes/Intervention\Image\Gd\Commands\ResponseCommand.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/oop/core/init.php
>   on line 16

Somehow the auto loader tries to include the libraries from my `classes`  directory where other classes resides. Any help how to stop this will be very helpful.

Comment: Show the part in your code where you autoload your classes.

Comment: I have given the autoload function in the question. That function is in a file called `init.php`. I am including `init.php` in every script. That's it.